Telegraf could not send data to Influx with precision in seconds
I have recently tried changing the precision setting in Telegraf to seconds, in order to improve the performance of Influx when storing data.
The configuration I used is this:
`
                                                                         /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf                                                                                   
[global_tags]
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 100000
  collection_jitter = "10s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "10s"
  precision = "1s"
  debug = false
  quiet = false
  logfile = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  urls = ["http://192.168.10.9:8086"]
  database = "monitoring_v1"
  tagexclude = ["influxdb_database"]
  [outputs.influxdb.tagpass]
    influxdb_database = ["monitoring"]
[[inputs.socket_listener]]
  service_address = "udp://0.0.0.0:8094"
  data_format = "influx"
  content_encoding = "identity"
  [inputs.socket_listener.tags]
    influxdb_database = "monitoring"


but when it came to checking if the metrics were written in influx I had this error:
2024-04-23T14:11:34Z I! [agent] Config: Interval:10s, Quiet:false, Hostname:"2f437ce63472", Flush Interval:10s
2024-04-23T14:11:34Z I! [inputs.socket_listener] Listening on udp://[::]:8094
2024-04-23T14:14:44Z E! [outputs.influxdb] E! [outputs.influxdb] Failed to write metric (will be dropped: 400 Bad Request): partial write: points beyond retention policy dropped=20


The metric format I am using for telegraph is this:
measurement,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag field,field,field,field,field timestamp in seconds (for example 1713874904)

and the retention policies of influx are:
    > show retention policies
name        duration  shardGroupDuration replicaN default
----        --------  ------------------ -------- -------
rp_3d       72h0m0s   24h0m0s            1        true
rp_1w       168h0m0s  24h0m0s            1        false
rp_inf      5376h0m0s 168h0m0s           1        false
rp_infinite 0s        168h0m0s           1        false

Has anyone had the same problem? I must have some configuration wrong in telegraph but I can't find it.
thank you!!
